# Function expecting pointer to pointer return giving "invalid conversion from '* const*' to '**' " error when returning an array of pointers

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors

The following code defines:

- A Vertex class, which contains an id and 3 coordinates (x, y and z) as private member variables
- A Triangle class, which contains an id and 3 Vertexes as private member variables

```
/*
-------------------------------------------------------
Class definition of the Vertex class
-------------------------------------------------------
*/

class Vertex
{
private:
    int id;
    float coordinates[3];

public:
    // Constructor
    Vertex(int newId, float *newCoordinates)
        : id(newId)
    {
        // copies coordinates across
        setCoordinates(newCoordinates);
    }

    // Copy Constructor
    Vertex(const Vertex &copiedVertex)
        : id(copiedVertex.getId())
    {
        // copies coordinates across
        setCoordinates(copiedVertex.coordinates);
    }

    // Destructor
    virtual ~Vertex() {}

    // Assignment Operator
    const Vertex &operator=(const Vertex &assignedVertex)
    {
        // if assigned itself, return reference to itself
        if (this == &assignedVertex)
            return (*this);

        setId(assignedVertex.getId());
        setCoordinates(assignedVertex.coordinates);

        // return reference to itself
        return (*this);
    }

    // --- Gets data from the object and returns it ---
    int getId() const { return id; }
    float getX() const { return coordinates[0]; }
    float getY() const { return coordinates[1]; }
    float getZ() const { return coordinates[2]; }

    // --- Sets data inside the object ---
    bool setId(int newId)
    {
        id = newId;
        return true;
    }
    bool setX(float newX)
    {
        coordinates[0] = newX;
        return true;
    }
    bool setY(float newY)
    {
        coordinates[1] = newY;
        return true;
    }
    bool setZ(float newZ)
    {
        coordinates[2] = newZ;
        return true;
    }
    bool setCoordinates(const float *newCoordinates)
    {
        // copies coordinates across
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            coordinates[i] = newCoordinates[i];

        return true;
    }
};

/*
-------------------------------------------------------
Class definition of the Triangle class
-------------------------------------------------------
*/

class Triangle
{
private:
    int id;
    Vertex *vertexes[3];
    bool clearVertexes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            delete vertexes[i];
        return true;
    }

public:
    // Constructor
    Triangle(int newId, Vertex **newVertexes)
        : id(newId)
    {
        setVertexArray(newVertexes);
    }

    // Copy Constructor
    Triangle(Triangle &copiedTriangle) : id(copiedTriangle.id)
    {
        setVertexArray(copiedTriangle.getVertexArray());
    }

    // Destructor
    virtual ~Triangle() { clearVertexes(); }

    // Assignment Operator
    const Triangle &operator=(const Triangle &assignedTriangle)
    {
        // if assigned itself, return reference to itself
        if (this == &assignedTriangle)
            return (*this);

        setId(assignedTriangle.getId());
        setVertexArray(assignedTriangle.getVertexArray());

        // return reference to itself
        return (*this);
    }

    // --- Gets data from the object and returns it ---
    int getId() const { return id; }
    Vertex *getPointerToVertex(int index) const { return vertexes[index]; }
    Vertex **getVertexArray() const { return vertexes; }

    // --- Sets data inside the object ---
    bool setId(float newId)
    {
        id = newId;
        return true;
    }
    bool setVertexPointer(int index, Vertex *newPtr)
    {
        vertexes[index] = newPtr;
        return true;
    }
    bool setVertexArray(Vertex **newArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            setVertexPointer(i, newArray[i]);
        return true;
    }
};
```

I am trying to use `Triangle::getVertexArray()` in the `Triangle` copy constructor and assignment operator.

When compiling (g++) I get the following error:

```
In member function 'Vertex** Triangle::getVertexArray() const':
error: invalid conversion from 'Vertex* const*' to 'Vertex**'
```

Could someone please explain the source of this issue, and how to solve it in my context?

Comment: Since you presumably have put `const` in `getVertexArray`, you should be able to explain what it means.

Comment: `getVertexArray` is a `const` method, so all the fields in the object are `const`.  Which means in this context, the `vertexes` array is `const` and a pointer to it is a `Vertex * const *`

Comment: `Vertex *vertexes[3];` is not an array of 3 `Vertex` objects. `Vertex vertexes[3];` is an array of 3 `Vertex`es

Comment: @n. m. Doesn't the const just constrain the function so that it can't change the object? If that is the case, I can't see any changes that I am making to the object

Comment: If this worked, someone could do `myConstTriangle.getVertexArray()[0] = &newVertex;` and now they have edited something that was const.

Comment: What `const` does is **not** constrain the function. If it did just that, it would be useless. `const` changes the type of `this`, and thus the thing `this` points to, and thus all members of that thing, so that the function would not be able to call other functions with an inappropriate argument type, or return a value with an inappropriate type, or do anything else with `this` that could enable any other piece of code do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getVertexArray` is a `const` method, so all the fields in the object are `const`.  Which means in this context, the `vertexes` array is `const` and a pointer to it is a `Vertex * const *`

To fix it, you need to either remove the `const` from the method or add it to the return type.